# Table in Mathematica returns output values in the wrong order

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've embedded the steps of calculation for solving my system of equations in a Block. I then pass on the local variable values for that Block of code by using a function that is defined to be the Block and its output (see below). It all works great, except that when I try to evaluate this function for a series of parameter values using Table, I get return values in the wrong order.

The code is below. I didn't include all the functions that are necessary for its evaluation because the problem must lie in the way I define evaluationfun and will probably be obvious to more advanced Mathematica users. If all functions are needed, however, I'm happy to add them.

```
evalfun[nn_, naa_, qap_, qbp_, outvar_] := 
Block[{n = nn, na = naa, qa = qap, qb = qbp, p = .1, \[Delta] = .9, 
out = outvar},

yeffafunMlit[yb_, xba_, Baeff_, Bb_] = NSolve[(u[yeffa, 0, Baeff, qa, p]) == (\[Delta] vam[yeffa, yeff[yb], xba, Baeff, Bb + yeff[yb] - yb, qa, p, n, na]), yeffa][[1]][[1]][[2]];

xbafunMlit[Baeff_, Bb_] = NSolve[u[yeff[0], xba, Bb + yeff[0], qa, p] == \[Delta] vam[yeffafunMlit[0, xba, Baeff, Bb], yeff[0], xba, Baeff, Bb + yeff[0], qa, p, n, na], xba][[1]][[1]][[2]];

Baeffsol = FindArgMax[u[yeffafunMlit[0, xbafunMlit[Baeff, Bb], Baeff, Bb], 
   Baeff - yeffafunMlit[0, xbafunMlit[Baeff, Bb], Baeff, Bb], 
   Baeff, qa, p] /. {Bb -> 1}, Baeff][[1]];

Bbsol = FindArgMax[u[yeff[0], 
  Bb - yeff[0] - na pcfun[n, na] xbafunMlit[Baeffsol, Bb], 
  Bb + yeff[0], qb, p], Bb][[1]];

Bbsoleff = Bbsol + yeff[0];

xbaMOlit = xbafunMlit[qa/(2 p), Bbsol];
yaeffMOlit = yeffafunMlit[0, xbaMOlit, qa/(2 p), Bbsol];
ybeffMOlit = yeff[0];
(*output desired outvar *)
outvar ]

(*Now evaluate evalfun for a range of values of qa output yaeffMOlit*)
Table[evalfun[21, 13, qi, -.5, yaeffMOlit], {qi,12,16}]
(* I get a return list with values in the wrong order *)
```

Comment: Could you eliminate almost all that, one item at a time, and just show a much simpler complete example that demonstrates this? You don't care what the calculated values are, only the order matters. You might even find the cause of this while doing that. If I just delete everything in the Block it doesn't seem to demonstrate this and I can't tell what to leave so I can see what you are seeing.

Comment: you could do `{qi,16,12,-1}` to reverse the order if that's what you mean.

Comment: Bill, I couldn't come up with a minimal example that reproduces the specific problem that the values were returned in a non-sensical order. However, in stripping down the code, I realized that I should either define my functions outside of the block, or give them a name local to the block. Errors were cropping up because of the fact that I was defining globals within the block.

Comment: Ah yes, some stuff has to be inside other stuff to work, some stuff has to be outside other stuff to work, and there are no sensible error messages explaining why something is wrong and what should be done about it. So, stripping the code helped. Wonderful. I had hoped that exercise might have exposed the problem. Is your problem resolved now?